# Indentity involving a product of a polynomial and an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

In the image below, the expression is depicted as a result of multiplying a polynomial by an infinite series, which is represented as an exponential function. Could someone kindly elucidate how the final equality is derived?
Thanks in advance.

[image: I can´t understand how to get the last equality]